# http streaming functionality with password

Tags: python, streaming, uv4l

I'm trying to add some http streaming functionality to an existing python motion detection script.

The script already uses the uv4l driver to access the raspberry pi camera, so I thought I'd try the streaming server that can be bolted to this driver. so I installed it, and to my surprise it only password protects the streaming configuration page and not the stream.

1) can the stream be password protected, and if so how?

2) I installed the extra driver by `apt-get install uv4l-server`, how would I uninstall this extra driver, and would it cause any problems with the uv4l driver?

3) whats the simplest way to stream from the raspberry pi cam with password protecting the stream, preferably in python?

note: I enabled the password protection on the control page by: `uv4l --auto-video_nr --driver raspicam --encoding mjpeg --server-option '--admin-password=blarblar'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the UV4L-server manual:

```
HTTP Basic Authentication:
       You  can  optionally  require  client  authentication by specifying one
       password for the 'user' user and one password  for  the  'admin'  user.
       Once  authenticated,  'admin' is allowed to access all the pages on the
       server. 'user' is allowed to access all the  pages  on  the  server  as
       well, but if both 'admin' and 'user' authentications are required, then
       only 'admin' is allowed to access the Control Panel page:

       --user-password arg
              require the client to provide the specified password for the
              'user' username
```

--user-password is what you need o set.

Comment: UV4L supports HTTPS as well now